# random.org with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, game-engine, game-development

I am trying to fetch a random number from an online service and I heard about Random.org with Unity but I don't know how to make it
Is there any example code to make?
I wrote this code

https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new

but got error:

> ?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new: HTTP Error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

```
void Start()
{
    // A correct website page.
    StartCoroutine(GetRequest("https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new"));
}

IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        // Request and wait for the desired page.
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
        int page = pages.Length - 1;

        switch (webRequest.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                Debug.LogError(pages[page] + ": HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                Debug.Log(pages[page] + ":\nReceived: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not to answer the question directly (I don't know the answer) but why not just use the built in `Random` class? It works well and you can provide a new seed at any time if you need to. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: Chances are they have put in some effort to stop people abusing their calls

Comment: @Absinthe It is a work task that I need to do because they use different algorithm and because we will use the server for this thing in our game

Comment: doesn't really make sense to me .. I wouldn't use the built-in but rather `System.Random` which can be also used in any other Asp.NET server outside of Unity .. @BugFinder I also tried to spam OPs URL in the browser and couldn't reproduce the error :'D .. so it seems odd unless it is/was really spammed onna per frame basis ^^ in which case indeed any decent online service will have a firewall with DDos protection kicking in ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is Mads here from Random.org. There are a few problems with your approach:

(1) You are using the old (and obsolete) Random.org API (https://www.random.org/clients/http/). The old API is still functioning, but it does not offer the same availability as the new (since 2016) API (https://api.random.org), which is why you will sometimes see the requests being refused by the servers.

(2) You are requesting only a single random number at a time. This is inefficient, because you have the full overhead of a HTTP request for a single random value. Unless you only need a single random value, it's also against the Random.org recommendations for use of the old API: https://www.random.org/clients/

The best solution is to use Random.org's new API, which has much better availability. The new API also has an official .NET library, which is supported for Unity. The library has a caching feature, which means you can avoid problem (2) above. The library is here: https://github.com/RandomOrg/JSON-RPC-.NET

With this library, you can use code like the following (adapted from the official documentation) to generate integers in the [1,6] range (like your code is intended to):

```
RandomOrgClient roc = RandomOrgClient.GetRandomOrgClient(YOUR_API_KEY_HERE);
RandomOrgCache<int[]> c = roc.CreateIntegerCache(1, 1, 6);
while (true) {
    try {
        int[] randoms = c.Get();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", randoms));
    } catch (RandomOrgCacheEmptyException) {
        // handle lack of true random number here
        // possibly use a pseudo random number generator
    }
}
```

Note: The first parameter to `CreateIntegerCache()` is the number of random values you want each `Get()` invocation to return. I left the calls to `Join()` in place in case you want to generate multiple values at a time.

P.S. You will find the full list of Random.org libraries here: https://api.random.org/json-rpc/4/source-code